# joining three sql queries

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

I am using sql server 2000 so cannot use CTE's

```
DECLARE @reportdate AS DATETIME

SET @reportdate='08/26/2013'
```

1st query

```
SELECT SUM(NENTEREDACD) AS calls,
       DINTERVALSTART
FROM   dbo.QUEUESTATS
WHERE  ( DINTERVALSTART > @reportdate + ' 00:00:00.000' )
       AND ( DINTERVALSTART < DATEADD(d, 1, @reportdate) + ' 00:00:00.000' )
GROUP  BY DINTERVALSTART
ORDER  BY DINTERVALSTART
```

2nd query

```
SELECT count(cname)   AS AvaiAgents,
       dintervalstart AS startdatetime
FROM   (SELECT dintervalstart,
               cname
        FROM   [dbo].[AGENTSTATS]
        GROUP  BY dintervalstart,
                  cname
        HAVING ( DINTERVALSTART > @reportdate + ' 00:00:00.000' )
               AND ( DINTERVALSTART < DATEADD(d, 1, @reportdate) + ' 00:00:00.000' )) T
GROUP  BY T.dintervalstart
```

3nd query

```
SELECT count(cname)   AS ActiveAgents,
       dintervalstart AS startdatetime
FROM   (SELECT dintervalstart,
               cname
        FROM   [dbo].[AGENTSTATS1]
        GROUP  BY dintervalstart,
                  cname
        HAVING ( DINTERVALSTART > @reportdate + ' 00:00:00.000' )
               AND ( DINTERVALSTART < DATEADD(d, 1, @reportdate) + ' 00:00:00.000' )) T
GROUP  BY T.dintervalstart
```

I want to only pull only the records from first query so it should be something like
so I need to get three columns from three different queries. The common thing is timestamp

```
I inetval     Calls  Avaiagents     Active agents
08/26/2012    20     22              23
```

Comment: Look into UNION ALL it will allow you to join all three queries into a single table

Answer (score 0):

cte's are just derived tables with the using keyword.  Can you do it the old fashioned way?

```
select somefields
from a_table join
(select etc) temp on t.something = a_table.something
```

Comment: the first is also a query

Comment: What difference does that make?